# WPF User control editable property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, expression-blend

This is my `UserControl` created in Blend:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF0084FF" Height="400">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,20,0" Text="Kategorija1" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
```

Now I want `TextBlock` text property to be editable so i can change it in c# code behind.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply give the TextBlock a name using the x:Name = "myTextBlock"

then in code behind you can use myTextBlock.Text = "some other text"

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF0084FF" Height="400">
    <TextBlock x:Name = "myTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,20,0" Text="Kategorija1" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

If you need to modify it outside of the class you can use the x:FieldModifier to make it public as well so that any outside class can modify it.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF0084FF" Height="400">
    <TextBlock x:Name = "myTextBlock" x:FieldModifier="public" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,20,0" Text="Kategorija1" FontFamily="Segoe Print" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26.667" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to edit the `TextBlock` in the code behind you need to give it a name by which you can access it.

```
<TextBlock Name="_textBox" ...
```

Now in the code behind you can access it by the name `_textBox`